# Регулярное выражение разбирает текст статьи только до первого перевода строки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть статья с разметкой и парсится страница с этой статьёй, и надо проверить совпадает ли они. То есть вроде всё должно быть просто, и в `online regexp tester` всё работает, а на деле только до переноса на новую строку

```
$regex="`".$page."(\s*)([\r\n]*)(\n*)`su";
$regex="`(".$page.")(\s*)(\n*)`s";
$regex="`".$page."(\s*)(\n*)`s";
$regex="`".$page."`s";

preg_match($regex, $cache_page, $result);
```

Помогите кто знает, буду очень признателен!

Comment: [m (PCRE_MULTILINE)](http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Comment: модификаторы я перепробовал и m и u и тд. Дело в том что если брать часть стать и искать в этой же статье только полной тогда всё находит. А вот если искать в спарсенной статье ( то есть там вся страница не только статья) тогда находит только первую строчку статьи до перехода на новую строку. Такое ощущение что в спарсенной не такой переход на новую строку что ли

Comment: В пересохраненной в базе спарсенной статье всё находит, а напрямую нет, Может переход на новую строку не совпадает или кодировка

Answer (score 0):

Запостил свой камент

```
<?php

$regex = '~'. preg_quote($page, '~') .'~iu'; 
preg_match($regex, $cache_page, $result);
```

Comment: Спасибо, это удобно, но тоже не помогло, только до перехода на новую строку, как будто они разными символами обозначены.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо модификатора su ставьте ismu

```
$regex="`".$page."(\s*)([\r\n]*)(\n*)`ismu";
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: нет, не работает. Если оставить только одну строку без пробелов и перехода на новую вот так 
<article id="post-519" class="clearfix post-519 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-bez-rubriki">

то текст вытягивает. А если вот так <article id="post-519" class="clearfix post-519 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-bez-rubriki">
                            <h1 class
То нет.(перед h1 пробел и перевод строки стоит)